TypeError start leafleat
I'm developing an angular app and I have a map using leaflet. Locally it works but when I upload it to render.com it displays the following error below:
main-2KC2FGCV.js:119 Erro ao carregar o Leaflet: TypeError: this.leaflet.map is not a function
at t.initializeMap (main-2KC2FGCV.js:119:669)
at main-2KC2FGCV.js:119:491
at f.invoke (polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:1:6450)
at Object.onInvoke (main-2KC2FGCV.js:7:29726)
at f.invoke (polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:1:6390)
at Y.run (polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:1:1715)
at polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:2:553
at f.invokeTask (polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:1:7075)
at Object.onInvokeTask (main-2KC2FGCV.js:7:29542)
at f.invokeTask (polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js:1:6996)

Below is the app.component.ts where I start the map:
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { PinService } from './services/pin/pin.service'; // Certifique-se de ajustar o caminho
import { Pin } from './models/pin/pin.model';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] // Correção de 'styleUrl' para 'styleUrls'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'map';
  items: any[] = [
    { label: 'Home', icon: 'pi pi-home', routerLink: '/' },
    // { label: 'Potencial IG', icon: 'pi pi-map-marker', routerLink: '/pin' },
  ];

  private leaflet: typeof L | null = null; // Adiciona a tipagem correta
  pins: Pin[] = [];
  selectedPin: Pin | null = null;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private pinService: PinService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      import('leaflet').then(L => {
        this.leaflet = L;
        this.initializeMap();
      }).catch(err => console.error('Erro ao carregar o Leaflet:', err));
    }
  }

  initializeMap(): void {
    if (!this.leaflet) {
      console.error('Leaflet não carregado.');
      return;
    }

    const map = this.leaflet.map('map').setView([-20.3222, -39.3700], 7);

    this.leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    this.pinService.getPins().subscribe({
      next: (pins: Pin[]) => {
        this.pins = pins;
        this.renderPinsOnMap(map);
      },
      error: (err) => console.error('Erro ao obter os pins:', err)
    });
  }

  renderPinsOnMap(map: L.Map): void {
    this.pins.forEach(pin => {
      console.log('Tentando adicionar pin:', pin);

      // Verifica se latitude e longitude são válidos antes de usar
      const latitude = pin.latitude ?? 0; // Usar 0 se for null/undefined
      const longitude = pin.longitude ?? 0; // Usar 0 se for null/undefined

      if (this.isValidCoordinates(latitude, longitude)) {
        const popupContent = this.generatePopupContent(pin);

        const marker = this.leaflet!.marker([latitude, longitude])
          .addTo(map)
          .bindPopup(popupContent);

        marker.on('click', () => {
          this.selectedPin = pin;
          console.log('Pin selecionado:', this.selectedPin);
        });
      } else {
        console.warn('Coordenadas inválidas:', pin);
      }
    });
  }

  isValidCoordinates(latitude: number, longitude: number): boolean {
    return latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90 && longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180;
  }

  generatePopupContent(pin: Pin): string {
    // Garantir que os dados sejam do tipo esperado
    const nome = pin.nome || 'Nome não disponível'; // Valor padrão se nome for undefined
    const cidade = pin.cidade || 'Cidade não disponível'; // Valor padrão se cidade for undefined
    const nivelMaturidade = pin.nivelMaturidade ?? 0; // Usar 0 se for null/undefined
    const tipoIndicacao = pin.tipoIndicacao || 'Tipo não disponível'; // Valor padrão se tipoIndicacao for undefined

    return `
      <b>Nome:</b> ${nome}<br>
      <b>Cidade:</b> ${cidade}<br>
      <b>Maturidade:</b> ${this.generateRating(nivelMaturidade)}<br>
      <b>Tipo de Indicação:</b> ${this.formatIndicationType(tipoIndicacao)}
    `;
  }

  generateRating(maturidade: number): string {
    return maturidade > 0 ? '⭐'.repeat(maturidade) : 'N/A';
  }

  formatIndicationType(tipoIndicacao: string): string {
    const tipoMap: { [key: string]: string } = {
      'IDENTIFICACAO_PROCEDENCIA': 'Identificação de Procedência',
      'DENOMINACAO_ORIGEM': 'Denominação de Origem'
    };
    return tipoMap[tipoIndicacao] || tipoIndicacao;
  }
}

I'm a bit lost on what to do to get the map to start and load the pins.
Here's the project URL: https://map-1sn5.onrender.com/
Local host works
I have tried to start leaflet in several different ways but none of them work.

It looks very strange that you do 'import * as L from 'leaflet';' and later on 'import('leaflet').then(L => {'...  maybe remove one of the imports, or change the top import to only use import tpye * as L at the top (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html)

Replace the line of code
const map = this.leaflet.map('map');

with
const map = L.map('map');

